# How do I download and save a file locally from a file input?

Tags: javascript

How can I take a file uploaded from a file input and save it locally with just plain vanilla JavaScript?

Update: I’m trying to take the uploaded file and display it on another page with an  element.

Comment: You can save the information in the local storage as an array, but you should show us what you have tried.

Comment: I haven’t tried anything that was remotely successful. I’ve been going around but can’t find anything. What should I save to local storage? How can I retrieve that and display it on a page with an image element?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Comment: Why do you need to save it locally? File inputs can accept only local files - so the file is already saved locally on your computer.

Comment: I’m trying to take the uploaded file and display it on another page with an <img> element.

Comment: In order to get a file uploaded to your server so you can use it, you are going to need something on the server side to process and save it. So you will need a server side language something like PHP for example.

Comment: I dont know what the file is, but depending, say if it is an image, you can load it as a base64 3encoded string which is then rendered to the screen in an element tag.

Comment: What is the relationship between the page with the file input and the page where the file is "displayed" ?